# Hosting Cyrillic

Tags: php, encoding, file, character-encoding, hosting

I have a problem with the Cyrillic on 2 hosts. One host is bg the other is en, on the bg host, the Cyrillic is ok, but on the en it isn't. All that is on Cyrillic just is outputed like **??????????**. In the database of the en host everything is on Cyrillic and it's ok, but when output it's **????** .The files are ANSI, but this is not a problem because on the bg host it's working fine, but on the en host, when they are ANSI , and there is some Cyrillic in the files they output the Cyrillic like **?????????** .

Comment: Needs more context and code. What encoding are the database tables in? What code are you using to connect to the database? What does the page's output encoding look like?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the 2 hosts return different `Content-type` header (in terms of character set). Add `header('Content-type:text/html;charset=utf8');` (or cp1251 if you are using 1251 encoding) and it should work. The other option is the default character set of the mysql connection to be different on the 2 hosts. Then you have to execute `SET NAMES utf8` query as the first query after connecting to MySQL and selecting the DB